# Selecting multiple items from combobox

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

Pls i want to know how to change the selectionmodel of javafxml combobox so that it can allow multiple seletion. Any contribution will be appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 16):

You could try an [ControlsFX CheckComboBox](https://controlsfx.github.io/javadoc/11.1.2/org.controlsfx.controls/org/controlsfx/control/CheckComboBox.html) ([ControlsFX](http://fxexperience.com/controlsfx/) is a 3rd party controls library for JavaFX).

[image: checkcombobox]

Just copied from the CheckComboBox javadoc:

> A simple UI control that makes it possible to select zero or more items within a ComboBox-like control. Each row item shows a CheckBox, and the state of each row can be queried via the check model.
>
> ```
>  // create the data to show in the CheckComboBox 
>  final ObservableList<String> strings = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
>  for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {
>      strings.add("Item " + i);
>  }
>  
>  // Create the CheckComboBox with the data 
>  final CheckComboBox<String> checkComboBox = new CheckComboBox<String>(strings);
>  
>  // and listen to the relevant events (e.g. when the selected indices or 
>  // selected items change).
>  checkComboBox.getCheckModel().getCheckedItems().addListener(new ListChangeListener<String>() {
>      public void onChanged(ListChangeListener.Change<? extends String> c) {
>           while(c.next()) {
>               //do something with changes here
>           }
>           System.out.println(checkComboBox.getCheckModel().getCheckedItems());
>      }
>  });
>  }
> ```

Note: the [JavaFX controls developer lead comments](https://community.oracle.com/thread/2389275) on the in-built combobox control for JavaFX:

> you can put whatever selection model instance you want into ComboBox, but only single selection will ever be supported. We did this as multiple selection didn't really make sense without drastic changes to the UI and UX, and we figured a separate control could be developed in the future to better support this use case

The CheckComboBox control from ControlsFX is that seperate control.

Comment: Perfect solution but god that thing is ugly.

Comment: Is there a way to allow the checkcombobox to take in user inputs like a combobox? This would be helpful when there are many many options in the checkcombobox

Comment: @YHStan  Please ask your question as a new question.

Comment: getSelectedItems method does not exist. Shouldn't be 'getCheckedItems' method? Also, the first link is broken.

Comment: The answer was created many years ago.  The documentation was moved, so I fixed the documentation to link to the current version of ControlsFX library (11.1.2).  I also updated the code sample copied from the documentation to use the current version version the API (uses `getCheckedItems`instead of `getSelectedItems`).

Answer (score 10):

I need something similar and this solved my problem.

```
@FXML
public MenuButton menuButton;  
......  
CheckBox cb0 = new CheckBox("x");  
CustomMenuItem item0 = new CustomMenuItem(cb0);  
CheckBox cb1 = new CheckBox("y");  
CustomMenuItem item1 = new CustomMenuItem(cb1);  
item0.setHideOnClick(false);  
item1.setHideOnClick(false);  
menuButton.getItems().setAll(item0,item1);
```

Comment: Combobox and Menubutton are different controls. The OP wanted a Combobox.

Comment: Yes, but it is anyways a constructive answer. I preferred this solution.

Comment: It is also possible to replace a combination of {CheckBox, CustomMenuItem} with a single {CheckMenuItem}. An example of the code is at [javawiki.sowas.com](http://javawiki.sowas.com/doku.php?id=javafx:combobox-multi-selection). Also, it is possible to add a listener to automatically rename the MenuButton based on the list of selected items. For example with String.join().

Comment: I really like this answer. I have been trying all day to corporate this answer into a tableview with little success. Can it be done easily?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old post, but here is just a minimalist working solution as described by @user82426 comment with the 'joining' part suggested. This was built using, as mentioned, http://javawiki.sowas.com/doku.php?id=javafx:combobox-multi-selection.

As stated it's not a COMBOBOX, but a MENUBUTTON... Nevertheless it does fill the needs I was looking for better than a COMBOBOX, so I thought it could help other ;-)...

Here it is :

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.CheckMenuItem;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.control.MenuButton;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class MultiSelectionComboDemo extends Application {
    final ListView<String> selectedItems = new ListView<>();
    
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        final String sMenuTextStart = "Fruit : ";
        final String sMenuTextEmpty = "[empty]";
        final MenuButton            choices = new MenuButton(sMenuTextStart+sMenuTextEmpty);
        final List<CheckMenuItem>   items   = Arrays.asList(new CheckMenuItem("Apple"), new CheckMenuItem("Banana"), new CheckMenuItem("Pear"), new CheckMenuItem("Kiwi"));
        choices.getItems().addAll(items);
        
        for (final CheckMenuItem item : items) {
            item.selectedProperty().addListener((observableValue, oldValue, newValue) -> {
                if (newValue) {
                    selectedItems.getItems().add(item.getText());
                } else {
                    selectedItems.getItems().remove(item.getText());
                }
                String sMenuText = sMenuTextStart + (selectedItems.getItems().size()>0?"":sMenuTextEmpty);
                choices.setText(sMenuText+String.join(", ", selectedItems.getItems()));
            });
        }
        
        BorderPane borderPane = new BorderPane();
        borderPane.setTop(choices);
        borderPane.setCenter(selectedItems);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(borderPane, 400, 300));
        primaryStage.show();
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look to the source code of ComboBox class, it says that "A ComboBox  only supports single selection". So you need to make a your own combobox, or use a library, i recommend controlsFX.