# Extending JFX ComboBox UI for MultipleSelectionModel

Tags: java, user-interface, combobox, javafx

I want to implement a MultipleSelectionModel ComboBox for Open Java FX 8, which would include all of the functionalities of the ControlFX CheckComboBox (as seen in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26186572/selecting-multiple-items-from-combobox)) plus other supplementary functions that are out of the scope of this question.

My issue is that I have been reading through the [JavaFX source](http://grepcode.com/snapshot/repo1.maven.org/maven2/net.java.openjfx.backport/openjfx-78-backport/1.8.0-ea-b96.1/) for hours now and I have yet to find in which method 1. the ComboBox creates the list of element to print (using ListView and other JFX UI elements) and 2. the ComboBox receives the event to show the list and shows it.
Could you help me find these methods?

I have read through the following classes:

```
javafx.scene.control.ComboBox,
javafx.scene.control.ComboBoxBase,
com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.ComboBoxBaseSkin,
com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ComboBoxBaseBehavior,
javafx.scene.control.Cell
```

and some other unrelated classes like the MultipleSelectionModel.

I plan to extend ComboBoxBase to make my MultipleComboBox. I have yet to be able to determine if ComboBoxBase can support MultipleSelectionModel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard location for sources is [here](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/8/master/rt/file/f89b7dc932af/modules/).

I don't understand the first question: "the ComboBox creates the list elements to print". What does this mean?

For 2: `ComboBoxBaseSkin` registers a listener with the `comboBox`'s `showingProperty()` (this is done in the constructor). The `handleControlPropertyChanged(...)` method invokes `show()` or `hide()` when the property changes. These are abstract methods, implemented in the subclass `ComboBoxPopupControl`; the implementation of `show()` in that class basically just calls `show(...)` on the `PopupControl` that holds the list view. The content of the popup (i.e. the list view) is created in the subclass `ComboBoxListViewSkin`.

The actual trigger to show the popup is managed by calling the `ComboBox`'s `show()` method, which causes the `isShowing` property to be set to true, triggering the listener described above. This is done from the `ComboBoxBaseBehavior` method.

Comment: For 1: By that I mean the method that creates the UI for the list and its elements by receiving the showing event. I'm simply trying to find where the UI for the dropdown list is built.

Comment: Ok, so I think I addressed that in the answer; the ListView is built in ComboBoxListViewSkin

Comment: Definitely, great answer, thanks a lot! (Would vote you up, but I don't have enough reputation)