# Use objects in Checked ComboBox controls FX

Tags: java, javafx, combobox, java-7

I have a combobox in my application that selects data fetched from a database but the problem is i need to make that combobox select multiple values .

I looked into this question on stackoverflow
[Selecting multiple items from combobox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26186572/selecting-multiple-items-from-combobox)

Taking into Consideration the comments i have changed the app to use java8 and checkedCombobox of ControlsFX.

But how to acheive the keyvalue pair association in this combobox is it possible.
As we could use setCellfactory in normal combobox.

My checked ComboBox

Class

```
/*
 Added for Application Lov
 */
package businesstier;

/**
 *
 * @author rahul_singh41
 */
public class KeyValuePair {
   private final String key;
   private final String value;

    public String getKey() {
        return key;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }


   public KeyValuePair(String key, String value) {
   this.key = key;
   this.value = value;
   }


@Override
    public String toString() {
        return key;
        }
}
```

Method

```
public static ObservableList<KeyValuePair> getKeyValue(Connection conFrom) throws SQLException{
        ObservableList<KeyValuePair> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        //data.add(new KeyValuePair("Select Application Name", null));
        KeyValuePair keyValuePair;
        String query = "select application_name,application_id from apps.fnd_application_vl";
        PreparedStatement ps = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        ps = conFrom.prepareStatement(query);
        rs = ps.executeQuery();
        while(rs.next()){
            //System.out.println("Key"+rs.getString(1)+"value"+rs.getString(2));
            keyValuePair = new KeyValuePair(rs.getString(1), rs.getString(2));
            data.add(keyValuePair);
        }
        //System.out.println("KeyValue pair"+data);
        return data;

    }


 @FXML
    private CheckComboBox<KeyValuePair> applicationCombo = new CheckComboBox<KeyValuePair>();
applicationCombo.getItems().addAll((AOLMethods.getKeyValue(connFrom)));
```

Comment: I'm not sure if it is, but you really should consider using Java 8 - JavaFX specifically has seen many improvements in Java 8, and some consider it the minimum version where JavaFX is actually useful.

Comment: actually where we use his toll not every machine will have java 8 so if there is anyother way to acheive this

Comment: My personal advice would be to either [package your application](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/deploy/self-contained-packaging.html) with a bundled JRE ensuring the correct version, or seriously consider Swing if you are forced to use JRE 7.

Comment: Are you paying for support for Java 7? If not, you will not receive any updates or bug fixes, even if they are critical or security related. Java 8 is more than three years out of general release now and Java 9 will be released in two months, so valid reasons for using Java 7 are few and far between. Supporting a software product that relies on a platform no longer supported by the platform vendor is a huge undertaking...

Comment: I get that @James but we get support for java 7 and my unit uses java 7 as that is what Oracle forms support so we are using that

Comment: If you want to use JavaFX and you are forced to support Java 7, your options are limited. I would agree with the sentiment that JavaFX is only really suitable for production from version 8 onwards. So either insist on users upgrading to Java8 to use the JavaFX application, or (probably your best option) use a self-contained application bundle with a Java 8 JRE, or accept the limited functionality of JavaFX 2.x (and perhaps implement your own `CheckComboBox` that works in JavaFX 2.x), or go back to Swing...

Comment: Note that the latest version of Oracle forms, to the best that I can tell, works fine with Java 8...

Comment: It not latest @James so that the issue , the forms here in my unit dosent work on 8 may be configuration issue but we cannot change taht for the tool

Comment: I have figured out another way its not good but its will do the job but stuck in issue updating the question