# How to select multiple values by using ComboBoxTableCell or ChoiceBoxTableCell in Table View javafx

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-tableview

I have a tableview where user can double click on a column row & Combo Box drop down will appear with list of items. Here problem is user can only select one value at a time instead I want to allow user to select multiple values.

Existing Implementation using ComboBoxTableCell

```
List<TableColumn<DITComparatorFileColumnConfigDO, ?>> columnList = new ArrayList<TableColumn<DITComparatorFileColumnConfigDO, ?>>();
TableColumn<DITComparatorFileColumnConfigDO, String> column = null;

column.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<DITComparatorFileColumnConfigDO, String>("primaryColumn"));
column.setCellFactory(ComboBoxTableCell.forTableColumn(FXCollections.observableArrayList(primaryFileHeaders)));
columnList.add(column);
```

[[image]]

Existing Implementation using ChoiceBoxTableCell

```
column.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<DITComparatorFileColumnConfigDO, String>("secondaryColumn"));    
column.setCellFactory(ChoiceBoxTableCell.forTableColumn(FXCollections.observableArrayList(secondaryFileHeaders)));
columnList.add(column);
```

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selecting multiple items from combobox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26186572/selecting-multiple-items-from-combobox)

Comment: I have gone through ControlFX 'checkComboBox' component earlier. It will be helpful if it is used outside tableview but I want it inside table cell factory. Please see the link to application screenshot.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49543019/adding-and-selecting-choicebox-thats-inside-a-tableview/49543306?noredirect=1#comment86102795_49543306

Comment: I have already tried with ChoiceBoxTableCell and it allows selecting one value at a time. I am also adding the implementation and screenshot

Comment: I have updated the question with both implementation. It would be helpful if you can demonstrate an example of selecting multiple values inside tableview cell

Comment: You have to write your own table cell implementation that incorporates a `CheckComboBox`. No-one is going to do that for you: try it and if you get stuck post a specific question here.

Comment: selecting multiple values is not supported by ChoiceBox nor ComboBox

Comment: it is not supported that why I am asking for the solution!!! That doen't mean to devote.

Comment: where did you get the impression that this site is for _doing_ your work for you? It's all about _helping_ you to come up with a solution ..

Comment: I am not asking to complete my code and give me ready made solutions. I have done lot of research and different approach to get the application up which you can see in screenshots. I am a beginner, instead devoting you can show some alternate path. I appreciate @James_D and I am trying to create custom cell factory.

Comment: I am trying to figure out this same thing, but there seems to be VERY LITTLE of this one the internet. I am not sure why this got down voted... The answer seems very heavy handed. Is there not an easier way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have implemented TurekBot *CheckComboBoxTableCell* which uses
>   ComboBoxTableCell and CellUtils implementations by replacing checkBox
>   to contolFX checkComboBox in it's original file.
>
> [Link to solution](https://github.com/TurekBot/CheckComboBoxTableCellDemo)
>
> [Screenshot from my application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/umNlr.jpg)

Comment: Your solution is pretty good, but it would be a WHOLE lot better if it could return the selected bound object rather than just a string. What would it take to do that? I have tried modifying it to get that functionality but i am having trouble.